# Resizing images without losing EXIF data?

Tags: imagemagick

I've written a little script that will download TIFF images from an FTP server, then resizes them and saves them as JPGs.

So far, so good, but in the compression step (listed below), I lose the EXIF data from the file.

Is there an elegant way to do the conversion / resizing / compression without losing EXIF data?

```
convert -limit memory 32 -limit map 64 sourcefile.tif -units PixelsPerInch -density 72 -quality 90 -resize 1500 targetfile.jpg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I've managed to figure it out - I was running an old version of ImageMagick (6.2.something). 

By updating it to the newest version, the TIFF EXIF bug was fixed. The above works fine - with ImageMagick 6.6.9-6 

Glorious.

Comment: You could answer your own question and mark it as accepted!

Comment: ...mark it as accepted and even upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

By updating it to the newest version, the TIFF EXIF bug was fixed, ImageMagick 6.6.9-6 Glorious works according to @palmaceous.

(I am adding this answer because I didn't notice the question was answered by the author of the question already. Felt someone would miss it as well.)