# ImageMagick Preserve Exif Data

Tags: resize, imagemagick, exif

I have a resizing function that does it's primary job right, but doesn't save
the exif data that comes with the original image file. Everything seems to be
correct until I call `->writeImage();` function, which seems to strip the exif
data of the image.

```
$resizeimage= new Imagick($image);

$exifDataArray = $resizeimage->getImageProperties("exif:*");

$resizeimage->thumbnailImage($width,$height);

$resizeimage->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$resizeimage->setImageCompressionQuality(90); 

echo $resizeimage->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'BLABLABLA');

$resizeimage->writeImage();


$updated= new Imagick($image);
echo $updated->getImageProperty('Exif:Make');
```

Note that If I `print_r($exifDataArray);` it shows the exif data
To make a change I put 'Exif:Make', 'BLABLABLA' and see if the
new exif data is written on the image, and it is written correctly

but after I `resizeimage->writeImage();`
No more exif data is present on the image file.

Can anybody help? Is there any way to keep the exif data on the image?

Answer (score 7):

It seems the error isn't there [for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840437/resizing-images-without-losing-exif-data).

A workaround I use at the moment:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -tagsFromFile $source_file $converted_file
```

Comment: Tried this.  It works as advertised.  Thank you!

Comment: More detail: Tried this with the convert function from ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25.  The EXIF information is still erased by convert.    exiftool  version 12.16 still fixes it using the workaround suggested by nadar.  Thank you nadar.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use the `thumbnailImage` image method if you want to preserve exif data. The following is from the documentation of ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#thumbnail):

```
-thumbnail geometry

This is similar to -resize, except it is optimized for speed and any image
profile, other than a color profile, is removed to reduce the thumbnail size.
```

You should use the method *resizeImage* instead (http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

Comment: Seems like -resize removes the rotation info also, at least as of version 6.8.6

Comment: @Michael It seems version 6.9.10 still have this problem.