# ImageMagic convert deletes exif data

Tags: imagemagick, exif, imagemagick-convert

with this small script, I am converting tif to jpg.

```
for f in *.tif
do  
  echo "Converting $f" 
  convert -quality 98% "$f"  "$(basename "$f" .tif).jpg" 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Converted successfully; Deleting $f" 
    # rm -vf $f
  fi
done
```

However, no exif data is preserved!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840437/resizing-images-without-losing-exif-data) thread says it had some problem long time ago, but not now.
Any idea?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-38 Q16 x86_64 2018-07-12 http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: Post a link to your tiff file with EXIF and I will check with more current versions of Imagemagick. You are using a somewhat older version. Current versions are 6.9.10.35 and 7.0.8.35. Also what is your version of libtiff and libjpeg? Are they current?